# How to change a selections options based on another select option without javascript

Tags: php, pdo, html-select

I'm not comfortable with jquery so I was wondering if there was another way of storing the value of the selected option and using it in a where clause in my second statement. I don't want to submit the form first. I would like to extract the value on change of the select option. I tried using javascript. I was able to extract the value but I couldn't use the variable in my where clause of the second statement.

Here's my code :

```
<?php

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM provinces');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<form method='POST' action='search.php'><select>";
    echo "<option value=''> Choose province </option>";

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $provCode = $row['prov_code'];
        $provID = $row['prov_ID'];
        echo("<option name='name' value='".$provID."'>". $provCode ."</option></br>");
    }
    echo "</select></br></br>";

?>
    <label for="district">District</label>
<?php

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM districts WHERE dist_prov_ID =**???(value of first select option)**');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<form method='POST' action='search.php'><select>";
    echo "<option value=''> Choose district </option>";

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $distName = $row['dist_name'];
        $distID = $row['dist_ID'];
        echo("<option name='name' value='".$distID."'>". $distName ."</option></br>");
    }
    echo "</select></br>";
?>
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the trouble here is that all your code is PHP, not jquery.

Comment: I tried it with javascript and I was able to alert the id that I needed but I can work with that variable other than in that one function

Comment: An option tag does not benefit from having a `name` attribute.  That part can be safely omitted.  The same for the `<br>` tags following `<option>` tags -- just remove the useless `<br>` tags.  `fetch_all()` should not be used if you are going just iterate it in the same layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to perform in the browser without submitting the form between the first and second select options, it will have to be javascript.

However, if you're willing to let them select the first option, submit the form, then select the second option you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$selectedProvID = $_GET['prov_ID'] ?? '';

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM provinces')->fetchAll();
echo "<form method='GET' action=''><select name='prov_ID'>";
echo "<option value=''> Choose province </option>";

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $provCode = $row['prov_code'];
    $provID = $row['prov_ID'];
    $selected = '';
    if ($provID === (int)$selectedProvID) {
        $selected = ' selected';
    }
    echo "<option value='$provID'$selected>$provCode</option></br>";
}
echo "</select></br></br>";

if (!empty($selectedProvID)) {
    echo '<label for="district">District</label>';
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM districts WHERE dist_prov_ID = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$selectedProvID]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<select name='dist_ID'>";
    echo "<option value=''> Choose district </option>";

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $distName = $row['dist_name'];
        $distID = $row['dist_ID'];
        echo("<option value='".$distID."'>". $distName ."</option></br>");
    }
    echo "</select></br>";
}
echo '<button type="submit">Submit</button></form>';
```

Note that you get the prov_ID value from the $_GET array at the top and only if it's defined do you select and display the second select field.

You also need to pre-fill the first select field with the correct data, you do that by including `selected` in the option tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit my post. I don't want to submit the form first. I would like to extract the value on change of the select option.

Comment: It must be GET though